# Invalid ARN when performing tagging operation on aws wafv2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-waf

I am trying to view and add tags on my web acls using `aws wafv2` cli command.
Other command seems to be working properly but I am getting the following error when using ARN in tagging.

The command:

```
aws wafv2 list-tags-for-resource \
    --resource-arn arn:aws:wafv2:us-east-1:<account_id>:global/webacl/<acl_name>/<acl_id>
```

Output:

```
An error occurred (WAFInvalidParameterException) when calling the TagResource operation: 
Error reason: The ARN isn't valid. A valid ARN begins with arn: and includes other 
information separated by colons or slashes., field: RESOURCE_ARN, parameter: <arn>
```

Any idea on why this is happening? I understand that the old version `aws waf` uses a different format. But I am using `wafv2` now so I think I am using the correct URL format already.

Comment: In which region are you making the api call? And have you tried using the correct capitalization? (Dont know if this matters; just a suggestion). Maybe you can share the acl name and acl id just to double check?

Comment: `ap-northeast-1` - but since the webacl setup is global, the region should be `us-east-1` correct?

I just copied the exact same ARN returned by `aws wafv2 list-web-acls --scope CLOUDFRONT --region us-east-1`

Comment: Maybe add --region us-east-1 to your list-tags call?

Comment: Yep, it worked. Someone pointed this out too.
Though I am confused since the default profile in my `~/.aws/config` is in `us-east-1`

Answer (score 1):

Just confirmed the fix. As the comment above indicated, I just need to add the `--region` parameter and it **needs to match** the region indicated in the ARN.

Though I am not sure why this is happening as the region in my `~/.aws/config` is default to `us-east-1` already.